# Dividing udp datagram messages

Tags: python, json, sockets, udp, datagram

i am trying to send a message through UDP (a list of dictionaries that i used json.dumps on it) and i get this error:
***OSError: [WinError 10040] A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself***

This is the client side code:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = (SRVR_NAME,DST_PORT)
packet_info = json.dumps(packet_info)
packet_info = packet_info.encode()
sock.sendto(packet_info,server_address)
sock.close()
```

and this is the server side code:

```
listening_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = (IP, PORT)
listening_sock.bind(server_address)
client_msg, client_addr = listening_sock.recvfrom(MSG_SIZE)
d = json.loads(client_msg)
d = d.decode()
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

My psychic powers suggest you are trying to put more than 64KB of data into a single UDP packet.

Maximum size of an IP packet including all headers is 65535 bytes.  IP and UDP headers combine for at least 28 bytes.  So the max size of the data portion of a UDP datagram is `65535-28 == 65507`.

Check the size of your encoded `packet_info` before sending.  If it's too big to fit, then split into multiple messages and handle accordingly.